# Nested rows in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a grid in Bootstrap 3.3.7 which is nested in another parent grid.

Here's the HTML:

**Parent component**

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 border">.col-md-3</div> // 
      <div class="col-md-9 border">
        <nested-app></nested-app> // should have 9 cols
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Nested component** // Should have 9 cols

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 border">.col-md</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 border">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 border">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the width of `col-md-1` inside nested component is not the same as `col-md-1` in parent component.

[here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-grid?file=app/app.component.ts)

So my question how can I make the same width of columns as parent grid in a nested grid?

Answer (score 0):

Columns have *percentage* based widths, so there always going to consume some percentage of their containing row.

For example, `col-*-1` is 8.333333% the width of its parent row.

Therefore, the row>col nested inside the parent `col-md-9` has 12 more smaller columns (not 9 more). As a result, the inner `col-*-1` is going to be narrower because it's consuming 8.333333% the `col-md-9`, which is *less than* 8.333333% of the outer container.